# Keyboard got disabled until Ubuntu login screen (requesting ideas for 4 questions)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, bios

My situation:

- a HP Laptop Pavilion Model 15
- Ubuntu 18
- Before Ubuntu Login Screen: Keyboard not working except Ctrl+Alt+Del
- On Ubuntu Login Screen: Keyboard fully functionable
- No PS/2 port
- Motherboard does not have jumper, no CMOS battery
- Tried removed battery and charger, screen did show "CMOS Reset"
- Cannot enter BIOS because keyboard not work
- Wasn't disabled before, and this started a few months ago.

Anyone has ideas on one of these:

- how to get keyboard back working all time?
- how to get keyboard NOT working before OS loaded, without accessing BIOS?
- possible to read/write BIOS settings on Ubuntu?
- without access to BIOS to make USB the first bootable device, how to install a new OS?

Answer (score 0):

I mounted and boot from my Windows HDD, went to control panel > security and update > recovery > restart which allowed me to choose booting from a USB device.

Basically, the problem that my keyboard can't work before loading into a login screen persists, but at least now I have a way to bypass BIOS to boot from my USB.